# React-beautiful-dnd: Droppable: Children is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I've been making Draggable Material-UI tree using 'react-beautiful-dnd', but I get the following error:

```sh
Uncaught TypeError: children is not a function
    at Droppable (react-beautiful-dnd.esm.js:8346)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    ...
```

Am I missing some necessary property should've been passed?

According to [this issue](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/1372), he fixed it with a wrapping `div` element, but in my case, React claims same issue.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TreeView from '@material-ui/lab/TreeView';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ChevronRightIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import TreeItem from '@material-ui/lab/TreeItem';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

const datas = [
  { "id": 2, "label": "aaa" },
  { "id": 3, "label": "bbb" },
  { "id": 4, "label": "ccc" }

]

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 216,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400,
  },
});

export default function DndTreeView() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);

  const handleToggle = (event, nodeIds) => {
    setExpanded(nodeIds);
  };

  const handleSelect = (event, nodeIds) => {
    setSelected(nodeIds);
  };

  const onDragEnd = () => {
    alert(1)
  }

  return (
    <DragDropContext>

      <Droppable droppableId="todos">
        <TreeView
          className={classes.root}
          defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
          expanded={expanded}
          selected={selected}
          onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
          onNodeSelect={handleSelect}
        >
          <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
            {datas.map((data) =>
              <Draggable key={data.id}>
                <div>
                  <TreeItem key={data.id} nodeId={data.id} label={data.label} />
                </div>
              </Draggable>
            )}
          </TreeItem>
        </TreeView>
      </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext >
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wrapping is not as per the doc. it is done with render props pattern.

[Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/prakash-react-beautiful-dnd-material-ui-tree-ksxui)

```js
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

const datas = [
  { id: 2, label: "aaa" },
  { id: 3, label: "bbb" },
  { id: 4, label: "ccc" }
];

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    height: 216,
    flexGrow: 1,
    maxWidth: 400
  }
});

const grid = 8;

const getItemStyle = (isDragging, draggableStyle) => ({
  // some basic styles to make the items look a bit nicer
  userSelect: "none",
  padding: grid * 2,
  margin: `0 0 ${grid}px 0`,

  // change background colour if dragging
  background: isDragging ? "lightgreen" : "grey",

  // styles we need to apply on draggables
  ...draggableStyle
});

const getListStyle = (isDraggingOver) => ({
  background: isDraggingOver ? "lightblue" : "lightgrey",
  padding: grid,
  width: 250
});

export default function DndTreeView() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([]);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);

  const handleToggle = (event, nodeIds) => {
    setExpanded(nodeIds);
  };

  const handleSelect = (event, nodeIds) => {
    setSelected(nodeIds);
  };

  const onDragEnd = () => {
    alert(1);
  };

  return (
    <DragDropContext>
      <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <div
            {...provided.droppableProps}
            ref={provided.innerRef}
            style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
          >
            <TreeView
              className={classes.root}
              defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
              defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
              expanded={expanded}
              selected={selected}
              onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
              onNodeSelect={handleSelect}
            >
              <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
                {datas.map((data, index) => (
                  <Draggable draggableId={`${data.id}`} index={index}>
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                      <div
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        style={getItemStyle(
                          snapshot.isDragging,
                          provided.draggableProps.style
                        )}
                      >
                        <TreeItem
                          key={data.id}
                          nodeId={data.id}
                          label={data.label}
                        />
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </TreeItem>
            </TreeView>
          </div>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it works like a charm! Can I ask you just one more question? I want my tree to be working like Windows folder drag and drop, so each treeitems can be put in each other. For now, thanks to your answer, drag-n-drop works fine but each items push each other. Shold treeitems also be wrapped by Droppable to implement this?

Comment: Could you please give an advice on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651173/react-beautiful-dnd-how-to-make-each-item-can-be-put-in-each-other

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake in REACT but for me it was not working because i had a semicolon after }

```
  <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
                    <Droppable
                        droppableId="tabs"
                        direction='horizontal'
                    >
                        {provided => (
                            <div
                                ref={provided.innerRef}
                                {...provided.droppableProps}
                            >
                                {tabs.map((tab, i) => (
                                    <Draggable
                                        key={tab.id}
                                        draggableId={tab.id}
                                        index={i}
                                    >
                                        {(provided, snapshot) => (
                                            <div key={i} ref={provided.innerRef} isDragging={snapshot.isDragging} {...provided.dragHandleProps} {...provided.draggableProps}>
                                               
                                            </div>
                                        )}
                                    </Draggable>
                                ))}; // issue
                            </div>
                        )}; // issue
                    </Droppable>
                </DragDropContext>
```